# Prove or disprove if $f:G\to K$ is group homomorphism then necessarily $|kerf|\le |imf|$

Tags: graph-theory, group-homomorphism

I wrote a counterexample:
$$G=(\Bbb Z_5,+_{mod 5})=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$$
$$K=(\Bbb Z_3,+_{mod 3})=\{0,1,2\}$$
$$e_k=0,f(a)=3a$$
so: $kerf=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and $imf=\{0\}$

my counterexample is right?
$$$$Thanks.

Comment: What is $e_k$? Your example ist essentially $f(a) = 0$?

Comment: $e_k$ is the identity element of $K$.

Comment: By the way you shouldn't have to specify that the identity element is mapped to the identity. All well-defined group homomorphisms do so automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, your counterexample looks good.

In general if you have groups $G$ and $H$ you can consider the morphism $\varphi: G\rightarrow H$ defined by $\varphi(g)=e_H$ for all $g\in G$.

The image is $\{1_H\}$ and the kernel is $G$. So this is a valid counterexample whenever $G$ is not trivial.